# Find Closest link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items that looks similar to this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page1.html"></a> </h3>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Item Details</p>
      <a href="#" class="linktoitem">Click Here</a> </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page2.html"></a> </h3>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Item Details</p>
      <a href="#" class="linktoitem">Click Here</a> </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page3.html"></a> </h3>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Item Details</p>
      <a href="#" class="linktoitem">Click Here</a> </div>
  </li>
```

My aim is to add to Click Here linkk from inside h3 inside the same li. HEre is how Im trying to do it:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var linkitem = $('.linktoitem').closest('h3').find('a').attr('href');
    $('a.linktoitem').attr('href' , linkitem) 
});
```

Unfortunately link comes out as undefined.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: "My aim is to add to Click Here linkk from inside h3 inside the same li.". What do you mean by this?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that inside the list tag I want my links to have the same target. First is in HTML <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page3.html"></a> </h3> and the second needs to be inherited from the one in the same list tag, so the final results looks like this : <li>
    <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page3.html"></a> </h3>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Item Details</p>
      <a href="page3.html" class="linktoitem">Click Here</a> </div>
  </li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var linkitem = $('h3 a', this).attr('href');
    $('a.linktoitem', this).attr('href' , linkitem) 
});
```

if my mind reading proved correct: you wanted to achieve this html

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page1.html"></a> </h3>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Item Details</p>
      <a class="linktoitem" href="page1.html">Click Here</a> </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page2.html"></a> </h3>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Item Details</p>
      <a class="linktoitem" href="page2.html">Click Here</a> </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="headings"> <a href="page3.html"></a> </h3>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Item Details</p>
      <a class="linktoitem" href="page3.html">Click Here</a> </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/79ghE/

Answer (score 2):

Tried like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.details a', 'li').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/CR4qG/1)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `closest` only finds ancestors, whereas you're looking for a sibling of the parent:

```
 var linkitem = $('.linktoitem').parent().siblings('h3').find('a').attr('href')
```

The other answers are more efficient, but I thought it would be useful to point out your error.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it:

```
$('li').each(function(){
var href = $(this).children('h3').children('a').attr('href');
$(this).find('.linktoitem').attr('href',href);
})
```